# XAML WPF can I Bind to <Thickness.left>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, variables, binding

What i'm trying to do is Math Operations on Thickness.
I want The **Margin.Left** of an image to be relatively negative to the **TemplatedParent**'s **Padding.Left.**
What i'm failing to achieve is to set the **<Thickness.Left>** to the returned value of the conversion of the **TemplatedParent**'s **Padding** to just **Padding.Left** Using the Converter ***ThicknessDirectionConverter*** Bellow.
I have the following XAML code :

```
<Image.Margin>
    <Binding Path="Padding" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
            Converter="{StaticResource ThicknessConverter}">
        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
            <x:Array Type="System:Object">
                <Thickness Left="{TemplateBinding Padding,Converter={StaticResource ThicknessDirectionConverter},ConverterParameter='l'}" Top="0" Right="0" Bottom="0"/>
                <System:String>L</System:String>
            </x:Array>
        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
    </Binding>
</Image.Margin>
```

ThicknessConverter,which does Math operations between two Thicknesses

```
  public class ThicknessConverter : IValueConverter
    {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value is Thickness thickness && parameter is object[] parameters && parameters.Length == 2 && parameters[0] is Thickness offset && 
                        parameters[1] is string operations)
            {
                //l,t,r,b for positive
                //L,T,B,R for negative
                //use contains
                if (operations.Contains('l')) thickness.Left += offset.Left;
                else if (operations.Contains('L')) thickness.Left -= offset.Left;

                if (operations.Contains('t')) thickness.Top += offset.Top;
                else if (operations.Contains('T')) thickness.Top -= offset.Top;

                if (operations.Contains('r')) thickness.Right += offset.Right;
                else if (operations.Contains('R')) thickness.Right -= offset.Right;

                if (operations.Contains('b')) thickness.Bottom += offset.Bottom;
                else if (operations.Contains('B')) thickness.Bottom -= offset.Bottom;

                return thickness;
                }
                return Binding.DoNothing;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

    }
```

ThicknessDirectionConverter, Which returns just the value of Thickness direction

```
public class ThicknessDirectionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value is Thickness thickness && parameter is string par && par[0] is char direction)
            {
                //l,t,r,b
                switch (direction)
                {
                    case 'l':
                        double left = (double)thickness.Left;
                        return left;
                    case 't':
                        double left = (double)thickness.Top;
                        return left;
                    case 'r':
                        double left = (double)thickness.Right;
                        return left;
                    case 'b':
                        double left = (double)thickness.Bottom;
                        return left;
                }
            }

                return Binding.DoNothing;
            }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: TemplateBinding is also a Binding. A simplified notation of the TemplatedParent binding.
Bindings can only be set on a Dependency Property. Thickness is not a Dependency Object so its properties cannot be bound.
In my opinion, you need to use a MultiConverter.

Comment: Yes thank you, I fixed the problem using **IMultiValueConverter**